# Xampp 1.7.4 and PHP 5.3.5 (Deprecated warnings)

Tags: php, xampp, pear

I just upgraded my Xampp installation to 1.7.4

I had a working script (jquery calling PHP script and showing the returned value).

After upgrade, my jquery is getting the result correctly, but in addition to the results, there are also some warnings that are returned, hence stopping my script to show the result (I checked in firebug). Here are the warnings:

> **Deprecated**:  Assigning the return value of new by reference is deprecated in **D:\xampp\php\PEAR\Config.php** on line **80**
>   
>   **Deprecated**:  Assigning the return value of new by reference is deprecated in **D:\xampp\php\PEAR\Config.php** on line **166**
>   
>   **Deprecated**:  Assigning the return value of new by reference is deprecated in **D:\xampp\php\PEAR\Config\Container.php** on line **111**
>   
>   **Deprecated**:  Assigning the return value of new by reference is deprecated in **D:\xampp\htdocs\phil\batteries\includes\class.db.php** on line **73**
>   ["Motor Cycle ","Scooter","Personal Watercraft ","Snowmobile","ATV","Ride-on Mower","Utility Vehicle"]

Keeping in mind the last line is the result being returned. but due to warnings, results are not populated. What can be the problem? I dont want to just off the error_reporting.

thanks

Comment: Try updating the pear packages.

Comment: Just as the error message, dont assign the return value by reference, instead try to store as value..

Comment: @kvijayhari: on line 73 of class.db.php, i have this code $database =& new MySQLDB(); 
i have also tried removing '&', still no change

Comment: You will get a warning anytime that assignment syntax is used. If you ore a previous dev used it in one place, chances are you used it all over the place. You need to correct everywhere you have done that or the warnings will persist. Alternately you can choose not to use the `E_STRICT` reporting level - fore example you might use `E_ALL` instead which is pretty much everything except whats covered by `E_STRICT`. Id recommend upgrading the code as much as possible though...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok here was the deal. The problem was in the PEAR files as mentioned in the warnings.

I just changed the files mentioned in the question. and removed

> =&

to

> =

and my script is up again. There were three warnings for PEAR files i.e

1. D:\xampp\php\PEAR\Config.php on line 80
2. D:\xampp\php\PEAR\Config.php on line 166
3. D:\xampp\php\PEAR\Config\Container.php on line 111

Answer (score 3):

A [bug was filed](http://pear.php.net/bugs/bug.php?id=13116) with the PEAR Config folks in **2008**.  They didn't act on it until last December, when [version 1.10.12](http://pear.php.net/package/Config/download/) was released.

If you can update that package, you should.  `pear update Config` (or maybe it's `pear upgrade Config`?) should do the job.

Answer (score 2):

PHP 5.3 marked a few older functions as deprecated, therefore your php scripts now complain if they're using one of those.

A dirty way to get round this would be changing the php error behaviour (either via php.ini or in the script itself while using [error_reporting](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php))

Better: Update your PEAR-scripts, if there are updates possible.

```
pear update-channels
pear upgrade-all
```

Try this in a safe enviroment first to avoid breaking even more code due to possible changes in the pear scripts you're using.

A good summary of all the changed functions which are now deprecated can be found [here](http://php.net/manual/en/migration53.deprecated.php).