# Deprecated: Assigning the return value of new by reference is deprecated in D:\xampp\php\PEAR\Config.php on line 80

Tags: php, xampp, php-5.3, deprecated

```
    <?php
/**
* This class is sort of factory class that is responsible for loading
* classes, it check if this class is not defined then it includes the file
* So developer don't need to worry about including that file
* @author Haafiz
*/
class load{

    public static $app_path= APP_PATH;
    public static $model_path=MODEL_PATH;


    /*
    * @param string $model_name <>Name of class(model) that is required to instantiate/load</p>
    * @param bool $continue_on_error  this decide whether to have fatal error or continue on error loading
    * $return object 
    */
    public static function model($model_name,$conitnue_on_error=0){
        if(!class_exists($model_name)){
            $model_filename= strtolower($model_name).".php";
            try{
                include self::$model_path.$model_filename;
            }
            catch(Exception $e){
                if(!$continue_on_error){
                die($e);
                }
            }
            $model=new $model_name();
            return $model;
        }       
    }
}

?>
```

In above code have to face following error. Some people says in some other threads that problem is in using `&` , I am not using that. So what actually is prolem in my case? All seems to doing every thing correctly. Saw some other threads but didn't find any solution. So please if other people understand any thing by it.
thanks

Comment: The problem is here: `D:\xampp\php\PEAR\Config.php on line 80`. And it _is_ very probable that there is a `&` being used there

Comment: This file doesn't look like your `Config.php` file... Where's all the configuration?

Comment: I seem to remember that assigning by reference was faster back in 5.1, and so it became common practice in some circles...  glad to see the situation is resolved and the practice deprecated now =)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Xampp 1.7.4 and PHP 5.3.5 (Deprecated warnings)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5617605/xampp-1-7-4-and-php-5-3-5-deprecated-warnings)

Answer (score 0):

Line 80 in `php/PEAR/Config.php` is indeed using a reference.

```
   function Config()
    {
        $this->container =& new Config_Container('section', 'root');
    } // end constructor
```

Please refer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5617605/xampp-1-7-4-and-php-5-3-5-deprecated-warnings) about this problem and about updating your PEAR package.

Comment: but this is not my file, it is from something that come along php, I tried updating pear but again having error in that too, pear try to update settings in wrong directory