# Assigning the return value of new by reference is deprecated

Tags: php, database-connection, xampp

I kept on receiving this error

```
Deprecated: Assigning the return value of new by reference is deprecated in C:\xampp\php\PEAR\Config.php on line 80

Deprecated: Assigning the return value of new by reference is deprecated in C:\xampp\php\PEAR\Config.php on line 166

Fatal error: Class 'mysqli_connect' not found in C:\xampp\htdocs\bb2\includes\classes\connection.php on line 3
```

I have no idea why, here's my code

this is config.php

```
<?php
    define("DB_HOST","localhost");
    define("DB_USER","root");
    define("DB_NAME","beatbeast");
    define("DB_PASSWORD","123192");
?>
```

and this is my connection.php

```
<?php 
    require_once('config.php');
    $mysqli = new mysqli_connect(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD, DB_NAME);
```

Comment: Look at the related questions, to the right, there are many similar questions.

Comment: First, are you sure you have mysqli included with PHP and your MySQL db is 4.1.3 or higher? --- try this $mysqli = new mysqli('localhost', 'my_user', 'my_password', 'my_db');

Comment: possible duplicate of [Xampp 1.7.4 and PHP 5.3.5 (Deprecated warnings)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5617605/xampp-1-7-4-and-php-5-3-5-deprecated-warnings)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You shouldn't be using `new` with `mysqli_connect` - the procedural versions of the `mysqli_` calls don't use object syntax.

If you want to use `new`, use `new mysqli()`.

As for the deprecation warnings, see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5617605/xampp-1-7-4-and-php-5-3-5-deprecated-warnings).

Comment: if I reinstall xampp with the latest version will it help?

Answer (score 0):

Check the mysqli is enable or not in php_ini file and also check the  file "php_mysqli.dll" is present in  C:\xampp\php\ext directory.

Comment: mysqli is enabled. also php_mysqli.dll is present

Answer (score 0):

you can disable deprecated messages by:

```
error_reporting(E_ALL | E_DEPRECATED);
```

or find the problematic line of code (function) and put an **@** in front of it.

Answer (score 0):

If mysqli is enabled then try this code chunk --

```
<?php
require_once('config.php');
$mysqli = new mysqli(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD, DB_NAME);
if (mysqli_connect_error()) {
    die('Connect Error (' . mysqli_connect_errno() . ') '
            . mysqli_connect_error());
}

echo 'Success... ' . $mysqli->host_info . "\n";

$mysqli->close();
```